# which mongodb-connection (admin or user) use to interact with the database

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm developing a c#-webservice which will provide some methods for the client to interact with the mongodb.

My question is: should I use the

--> admin-user to read/write from/to the database and take care of the authorization my self
 or 
-->should I create a connection with the current logged-in user and let the mongodb take care of the user-authorization?

I'm asking because for some user-actions I need to query the user-database (where only the admin has right to read/write) before I can execute the method where user-rights are enough.

Tobias

Comment: Which OS are you using? Which MongoDB subscription do you have?

Comment: Its a c#-Webservice on Windows. Maybe I will port it one day to linux (mono) but not in the near future ;)

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer is:** Take care of the authentication yourself inside your application.

**The medium length answer is:** That's mostly based on your opinion, and it's a question you need to answer  regardless of you database solution.

**The long answer is:** There are 4 different [authentication mechanisms](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/#authentication-mechanisms) supported by `MongoDB`:

1. MONGODB-CR - An internal challenge-response `MongoDB` mechanism.
2. x.509 Certificate (new in v2.6).
3. Kerberos (only on `MongoDB Enterprise`).
4. LDAP Proxy Authority (only on `MongoDB Enterprise for Linux`).

I assume you run windows, which uses Kerberos for authentication. I also assume that you don't have the `MongoDB Enterprise` subscription because it costs 3X the basic subscription. If those assumptions are correct, you can't really use the windows authentication of the logged-on user to access the DB. That means that you **must** handle authentication yourself.

I recommend using certificates. It's quite easy if your environment supports it, it ins't specific to `MongoDB`, and it's very secure.

Comment: its just an private-c#-project I always wanted to develop and never had the time. So I don't have any subscription yet ;) I think my question was a littlebit misleading. I will always create users inside mongodb and will not use Windows-Users or LDAP or something like that. I just wanted to know if it is enough to create the users with some read/write-privileges and let mongodb handle the authorization. This would mean that I let all requests from the client through to mongo...But I will make both. Take care of the authorization and (fallback) mongodb blocks it too.

Comment: @TobiasKoller Then go with the shortest answer. And use MONGODB-CR for authentication.